# Assignment Operator in StringBuffer not working

Tags: stringbuffer

```
public class Test
{
    static void operate(StringBuffer x, StringBuffer y)
    {
        x.append(y);
        y=x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StringBuffer x=new StringBuffer("Sun");
        StringBuffer y=new StringBuffer("Java");

        operate(x,y);
        System.out.println(x+","+y);
    }
}
```

his Prints : SunJava,Java

Can anyone please explain why it is printing like that instead of SunJava,SunJava ?

Answer (score 1):

You pass a reference to the StringBuffer in y to your operate function. Then in operate, you change the reference, but not the object. After the call to operate, your main function still has a reference to the StringBuffer it originally allocated.

Comment: Thank you. Got that part. But then why is x in main function getting changed by the append in operate function?

Comment: Think of x as a pointer to the StringBuffer. When appending to x, you are actually changing the state of the object x is pointing to. When assigning another object to x, you are actually telling x to point to a different object.

Comment: In case of passing objects it happens, but if I pass premitive then in main the value remain unchanged.

Comment: True. This is because a primitive value is basically a memory location and directly contains its value. When passing a primitive, the receiver gets a copy of this memory location. Altering the value only alters the data in its own memory location, not the original one. Objects are passed in the same way, however, you don't receive a copy of the object, but rather a copy of the memory location of the pointer to the object. Objects only reside in a single space in memory.